# Auto VS Static Variable Scope in C programming

Tags: c, variables, scope

Helloo!! I am currently learning about variable scope in C programming, auto, static and extern. I am running this code below and I am not sure why it works. I thought auto variables are only defined in the function it is defined in and does not retain its value? How is it that this code is working? Shouldn't the int a,b be static variables instead?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sum(void)
{

    auto int a,b;

    a = 91; b = 7;
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n",a,b,a+b);
}

int main()
{

    puts("Calling the sum() function:");

    sum();
    puts("done");

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't work?  What behavior were you expecting and why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are not *retaining* anything. They're always the same value because you're explicitly assigning them the same values in `sum()`.

```
a = 91; b = 7;
```

If you change your code to accept the variables as parameters instead, you'll get the output you would expect.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sum(int a, int b)
{

    printf("%d + %d = %d\n",a,b,a+b);
}

int main()
{

    puts("Calling the sum() function:");

    sum(91, 7);
    sum(23, 9);

    auto int x = 44;
    auto int y = 24;
    sum(x, y);

    puts("done");

    return(0);
}
```

If you try to access `x` or `y` from within `sum()` now, you'll get an error that they aren't in scope.